# Let $G$ be a group containing exactly $2n$ elements, $n\ge1$ integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group containing exactly $2n$ elements, $n\ge1$ integer. Prove that, $\exists$ $x\neq e$ such that $x^2=e$ where $e$ represents the identity of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$G = \{e\} \cup \{x : x = x^{-1},\,x\ne e\} \cup \{x : x \ne x^{-1} \}$$
and the lattermost set has even cardinality because inversion is an involution on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Pair up non-identity elements with their inverse.